# Using JustGage with Require.js

Tags: javascript, requirejs, raphael, justgage

JustGage uses Raphael, which as is well-discussed [here](https://github.com/DmitryBaranovskiy/raphael/issues/524), is not AMD compliant (and so doesn't work with Require.js).

I have not used Require.js before, nor done a lot of JS, so I am battling to get my head around this.  There has been a lot of trial and error ;)

Using the approach suggested [here](https://github.com/vraa/raphael-require), I have split the Raphael modules out into separate files and included them separately, as well as making a guess as to what to do for JustGage.

```
require.config({
    paths: {
        //other links removed
        'eve': 'vendor/eve/eve',
        'raphael-core': 'vendor/raphael/raphael.core',
        'raphael-svg': 'vendor/raphael/raphael.svg',
        'raphael-vml': 'vendor/raphael/raphael.vml',
        'raphael': 'vendor/raphael/raphael.amd',
        'justgage': 'vendor/justgage/justgage.1.0.1.min'
    },
    shim: {
        'eve': {
            exports: "eve"
        },
        'raphael': {
            deps: ['eve'],
            exports: "Raphael"
        },
        'justgage': {
            deps: ['raphael'],
            exports: "JustGage"
        }
    }
});
```

But the instructions then say "After the above configuration, you can start using Raphael like other require-js modules" which is not so helpful ;)

I think I need to do something in main.js?

In my cshtml page I have

```
require(["raphael", "justgage"], function(JustGage) {
    $(function() {
        var a = new JustGage({
            id: "pvgauge",
            value: @Model.GaugeValues.PV,
            min: @Model.PVGauge.MinValue,
            max: @Model.PVGauge.MaxValue,
            title: "Personal Volume",
            label: "PV",
            levelColors: gaugeSettings.levelColors,
            levelColorsGradient: gaugeSettings.levelColorsGradient,
            showInnerShadow: gaugeSettings.showInnerShadow,
            shadowSize: gaugeSettings.shadowSize,
            labelFontColor: '#7ACE30',
            titleFontColor: gaugeSettings.titleFontColor,
            valueFontColor: gaugeSettings.valueFontColor
        });
    });
});
```

Now this at least finds JustGage, but now gives the error `'Raphael' is undefined.`

(I have also tried just doing a script include directly in the cshtml file but get the error `'Mismatched anonymous define() module: function (eve) {'`)

Is my understanding correct that Require.js means things are not in global scope? And JustGage is expecting Raphael to be in global scope?

Any help on getting JustGage working? Or recommendations for an equivalent library for "speedo"-type gauges that will work with Require.js?

Answer (score 0):

almost there, you need add it to the function as well, so it's available to JustGage.

```
require(["raphael", "justgage"], function(raphael,JustGage) {
```

If justgauge is a module then you should load the dependency in the module, as it will be looking in that module for raphael, however as you've already loaded it, it should work,

it's easier to keep track of your dependencies and load them where needed,

```
define(['module' , "pathto/raphael"], function (module, raphael) {
```

Comment: Neither `require(["raphael", "justgage" ], function (raphael, JustGage) {` or `require(["raphael", "justgage" ], function (Raphael, JustGage) {` work - still gives `Raphael is undefined`.

Comment: I don't know enough for  "If justgauge is a module then you should load the dependency in the module" to make sense to me, sorry!  Appreciate the answer, though.

Comment: hmm, i can call raphael fine, but cant do anything with justgauge as it's no amd-fied if that's a word, run this http://codepen.io/sajrashid/pen/eNppov , if that works it's easy to wrap JUstgauge into a module (that does mean it will play well), i get away with more that 50%, anyway try that and well see

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
require('eve');
window.Raphael = require('raphael');
require('justgage');
```